# Using callback functions to update a JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, asynchronous

So I have a db_functions.js file that contains a few functions to interact with a database. Here's part of it:

```
function getUsers(client, fn){
    //var directors = {};
    client.keys('*', function(err, keys){
        keys.forEach(function(key){
            client.hgetall(key, function(err, vals){
            fn(key, vals);
        });
        });
    });
```

I use the getUsers function in another file:

```
router.get('/accounts', function(req, res){
    var dir = {};
    db_functions.getUsers(client, function(key, vals, cb){
        dir[key] = vals;
        cb(dir);

        function cb(f){
            var final_dir = {};

            console.log(f)
            res.json(f);
        }
    }

    )});
```

I'm trying to get some information from a database using a callback, update a JSON object with that information and when I've updated the object with all the information, send the JSON object as a response.

The problem is in the cb function, res.json is called multiple times which gives a "can't set headers after they are sent" error. res.json should only be called once dir is done updating

Comment: The function you pass to `getUsers` has a `cb` parameter, but you are also defining a function with name `cb` inside of it. That seems quite strange. However, you are not passing a third argument to the callback of `getUsers`, so I guess it's fine.

Comment: @FelixKling I read some tutorials and I thought that was a legal move. 
http://ablogaboutcode.com/2011/06/30/avoiding-nested-callbacks-in-javascript/

Also not sure if I'm being clear, but the code above isn't working as it should be. In the `cb` function, `res.json` is called multiple times which gives a "can't set headers after they are sent" error. res.json should only be called once `dir` is done updating

Comment: It's just confusing at first glance. Take this for example: `function foo(bar) { var bar = 42; return bar + 1;}`. It's not clear whether the function is supposed to take in an argument and the `var bar;` is the error or vice versa. Also, there is no benefit in creating a function and calling it immediately in this case. You could just write `dir[key] = vals; var final_dir = {}; console.log(f); res.json(f);` and it would have the same effect.

Comment: @FelixKling Added some edits, you replied before I finished writing

Comment: Yeah, that really wasn't clear from your question. I suggest you edit it and explain it better (with the info from your comment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> res.json should only be called once dir is done updating

Why not call the `getUsers` callback only after you collected all the data?

```
function getUsers(client, fn){
    client.keys('*', function(err, keys) {
        var values = {};
        var remainingRequests = keys.length;
        keys.forEach(function(key) {
            // Note that this will run keys.length requests in parallel
            // forEach does not (and cannot) wait for the async calls to finish
            client.hgetall(key, function(err, vals){
                remainingRequests -= 1;
                if (!err) {
                    values[key] = vals;
                }
                if (remainingRequests === 0) {
                    fn(values);
                }
            });
        });
    });
}

outer.get('/accounts', function(req, res){
    db_functions.getUsers(client, function(values){
        res.json(values);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. I was thinking there would be a "special" way to signal the getUsers function to only respond when dir was done.

Comment: If you'd use promises this could be solved a bit more elegantly with `Promise.all`, but no, there is no special or specific away to do this. You have to keep track of the "requests" yourself.

Answer (score -2):

Do you mean AJAX Callback methods ?
Like:

```
  var jqxhr = $.get( "example.php", function(return_data) {
    console.log( return_data );
  })
  .done(function() {
    console.log( return_data );
  })
  .fail(function() {
    console.log( return_data );
  })
  .always(function() {
    console.log( return_data );
  });
```

Comment: Nope, just regular javascript callback methods. I'm using nodejs and express.js if that makes a difference

Comment: This question is about Node.js, not jQuery.